# Adding totals to all rows and columns in a df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have as simple question, at least I think it is/?!

I have a df, see below and attached example, that I would like to add totals to all rows and columns in.  In reality the df I need to do it on has many more columns and rows so I need a solution that is not too time consuming please, that is does not sum each row column one at a time?

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Sanj", "Rob"), Date = c("12/08/2020", "13/08/2020", "14/08/2020"), Col1 = c(20, 60, 40), Col2 = c(40, 40, 40), Col3 = c(100, 233, 500)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name  Date        Col1  Col2  Col3
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Joe   12/08/2020    20    40   100
2 Sanj  13/08/2020    60    40   233
3 Rob   14/08/2020    40    40   500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also help, similar to @ThomasIsCoding:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% bind_rows(df %>% select(-c(1:2)) %>% summarise_all(.funs = sum)) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[3:5]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Name  Date        Col1  Col2  Col3 Total
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Joe   12/08/2020    20    40   100   160
2 Sanj  13/08/2020    60    40   233   333
3 Rob   14/08/2020    40    40   500   580
4 <NA>  <NA>         120   120   833  1073
```

**Update:** You can also add a `Total` label:

```
df %>% bind_rows(df %>% select(-c(1:2)) %>% summarise_all(.funs = sum) %>% mutate(Name='Total')) %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[3:5]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Name  Date        Col1  Col2  Col3 Total
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Joe   12/08/2020    20    40   100   160
2 Sanj  13/08/2020    60    40   233   333
3 Rob   14/08/2020    40    40   500   580
4 Total <NA>         120   120   833  1073
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  Perfect, the only thing I need to add is a name for row 4?

Comment: @Montana_innit96 I have added an update with code for what you want! Please check and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: that is perfect.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I still have a small issue: the actual df I want to apply this on actually has non-numeric data (my bad in original question!) in some columns and the the code is returning an error - Error in .Primitive("sum").... invalid 'type' (character) of argument.  Adjusted code for df example below:      df <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Sanj", "Rob"), Date = c("12/08/2020", "13/08/2020", "14/08/2020"), Col1 = c(20, 60, 40), Col2 = c('green', 'red', 'blue'), Col3 = c(100, 233, 500)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @Montana_innit96 Try using `as.numeric()` to transform such columns, and the you can try with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
df$total <- rowSums(df[grep("Col\\d+",names(df))],na.rm = TRUE)
```

or

```
df$total <- rowSums(df[-c(1:2)],na.rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Name  Date        Col1  Col2  Col3 total
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Joe   12/08/2020    20    40   100   160
2 Sanj  13/08/2020    60    40   233   333
3 Rob   14/08/2020    40    40   500   580
```

Comment: This is correct for the example, but surely the OP's columns aren't actually called `Col1` , `Col2`, `Col3` etc?

Comment: @AllanCameron Haha, that's right! Maybe `rowSums(df[-c(1:2)],na.rm = TRUE)`?